# Split a text file into multiple text files based on a criteria

Tags: vbscript

I have this text file and 3 other files similar in a folder that i need to parse and split into multiple text files based on Vendor name. There can be possible 8 Vendors in each report and as little as 1.

I am new to VBScript, but have a little bit of coding experience.

I have been able to read from the text file and find the vendor names, but i have not been able to grab all the data between the vendor names, nor create a separate file for each vendor.

I don't need you to write the script, but if you can feed me some part to get me moving i would be grateful

Here is the code i have far that is able to grab the vendor names (AMGENERAL, JOHN HANCOCK):

```
' This script will read the INS050 files

   Dim objFSO, strSearchFor, str, strVen, obj

 Const ForReading = 1
 Const ForWriting = 2
 strSearchFor = "1RUN"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = 
objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\P148044\Documents\INS050E.txt", ForReading)
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\P148044\Documents\TestData.txt", 
ForWriting)

do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then
For i = 1 to 3
' str = ""
' Wscript.Echo  str
str = objTextFile.ReadLine
str = Left(str,40)
strVen = str
Next

if strVen <> strVen2 Then

obj1.WriteLine(strVen)


End If
strVen2 = strVen
strVen = ""
End If

loop

obj1.Close
Set obj = Nothing
objTextFile.Close
```

Here is a sample of report:

[image]

Comment: have you used R before?, you can import these 3 text files and then split them into seperate text based on vendor

Comment: No i am not sure what R is

Comment: Its like a program like VBA but its specificaly made for data  problems like this. Can you a post a link to such a file and I can see how I can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code, please:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objTF, fullFilename, strIn, El, arr, arrI
Dim obj1, strVendorPath, strVendor, k, startV, endV, strV, i
'Put the searching elements in an array (they look to appear twice: ones with a short name and second with a longger one:
arr = Split("LINCOLN|LINCOLN NATIONAL,PROTECTIVE|PROTECTIVE LIFE,AMGENERAL|AMERICAN GENERAL,JOHN HANCOCK|JOHN HANCOCK,PACIFIC|PACIFIC LIFE INS,PRUDENTIAL|PRUCO LIFE", ",")
  fullFilename = "C:\Users\P148044\Documents\INS050E.txt"
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fullFilename, 1)
        strIn = objTF.ReadAll 'read the text to be analized at once
  objTF.Close

  For Each El In arr
    arrI = Split(El, "|") 'split the array elements in short and long parts
    startV = InStr(strIn, arrI(0)) 'find first element occurrence
    'look for the last occurence
    Dim lngStart
    For i = startV To Len(strIn)
        If endV = 0 then 
        lngstart = startV
        Else
            lngstart = endV + Len(arrI(0))
    End If
        If InStr(lngStart, strIn, arrI(0)) >= startV Then
            endV = InStr(lngStart, strIn, arrI(0))
        Else
            'I observed inconsistencies in the file construction and the short name is not all the time in the same place. 
            'I also observed that after the last occurrence a specific string ends the vendor area
            endV = InStr(endV, strIn, "TOTAL NEW PURCHASE LIFE")
            endV = InStr(endV, strIn, vbLf) + 1 'include the end of the line, too
            If endV = 0 Then endV = Len(strIn)'for the last array element in the string
            strVendor = Mid(strIn, startV, (endV - startV)) 'string area to be extracted
            'building the vendor name file, in the same location with the initial one
            strVendorPath = left(fullFilename, InStrRev(fullFilename, "\")) & arrI(1) & ".txt"

            Set obj1 = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strVendorPath, True, True)
                obj1.Write strVendor 'write the string at once
            obj1.Close
            Exit For 'exiting the loop
        End If
    Next 
    startV = 0: endV = 0 'reinitialising variables
  Next
  MsgBox "Ready..."
```

Please, test it and let me know if it does what you need. I hope you understand the code logic. I tried commenting it in order to make it clear...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212896/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-text-files-base).